# Node.js on Mac OS X getting error "Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, osx-mavericks

I recently bought my first Apple Mac (which is running Mavericks) on which I have installed node.js (of which I am also a novice).

I have run into an issue which hopefully someone will be able to provide me with a simple answer to.  I am getting the error...

`Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

I started the apache server, created a small html file called `browser.html` and placed it in /library/webserver/documents/

This allows me to view it at `http://localhost/browser.html`

This html file contains the following script…

```
$.ajax('http://127.0.0.1:8124/littletest.js', {
    success: function() {console.log('browser success')},
    error: function() {console.log('browser fail')}
});
```

I then created a file called `littletest.js` in the same folder as `browser.html` (I previously had it in /users/[my mac’s user name]/test/ but moving made no difference to the problem)

The contents of the `littletest.js` file are…

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello Node.js\n');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

By going to this folder in Terminal and entering node `littletest.js` the script starts.

But as mentioned above, when I browse to `http://localhost/browser.html` I get the error…

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8124/littletest.js. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I know this can be resolved by adding the following lines to the `littletest.js` file…

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```

…but surely it isn’t normal to have to do this every time, is it?!

Is this normal?  (because it generally never mentions anything about this in any of the examples I’ve read).

Or is it that I am setting up my environment wrong?  Please help!

Thanks for any assistance you can give because this has been perplexing me for some time now!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `127.0.0.1:8124` in one place and `localhost` in another.  You and I know that those are owned by the same person, but they look different to the browser, so the cross-origin access policies are enforced.  If you just normalize on one of those (it shouldn't matter which you use, as long as you're consistent) the problem should be fixed.  Note that this means both using the same domain (`127.0.0.1` or `localhost`) as well as using the same port.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but after changing all references in the files to localhost and calling `http://localhost/browser.html` I still got the same error.  I also tried changing all references in the files to 127.0.0.1 and calling `http://127.0.0.1/browser.html` but that also produced a similar result: _[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8124/littletest.js. Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (littlebrowser.html, line 0)_

Comment: @user1087668 Oh; I didn't notice the port part.  Those are going to have to be on the same port as well as the same domain.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.  By pointing the browser to use `http://127.0.0.1:8124/littlebrowser.html` it now displays the "Hello Node.js" message returned by the `littletest.js` file.  However strangely, there is no output to the colsole for the `success` or `error` functions in `littlebrowser.html`.

Comment: When calling `http://127.0.0.1:8124/littlebrowser.html`, the reason why "Hello Node.js" is now being displayed is because it's just the server being run due to `littletest.js` being processed.  In fact it doesn't matter what you put after `http://127.0.0.1:8124/`, it still displays the "Hello Node.js" message.  `browser.html` does not get called at all.  So I can't use the same port number for the browser URL html file that I use for the node file.  All of which means I'm back to my original issue.

Comment: @user1087668 You may want to look into [serving static files with express](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-static-content).  Apache is running port 80, not port 8124, so it is not surprising that it is not getting requests to port 8124.